# Plane waves vs continuous sine waves

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, plane-wave

I've started learning QFT from Sean Carroll's lectures, but I had to postpone it until I'll manage my notes))

Meanwhile, 1 question is bugging me: it's about 3D plane waves, which in QFT are analogous to field modes (continuous sine waves) - obtained when one calculates mode composition of some wave packet or another waveform in the Fourier series.

So, here ([timecode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dy1LNk_B6IE&t=1471)) he's saying that plane waves are characterized by "wave vector" $\vec{k}$, which gives information about the wavelength of that 3D mode via $\lambda = \large\frac{2\pi}{\text{| }\vec{k}\text{ |}}$, **emphasizing** that longer $\text{| }\vec{k}\text{ |}$ gives smaller $\lambda$ (as, of course, can be seen in formula).

My question is... how come sine waves (2D field modes), while being continuous (i.e., defined from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$), may have any $\lambda$ (as Fourier series tells them), **whereas** plane waves (3D field modes) are nor continuous, nor are free to have any $\lambda$ - ?..

Or, is he speaking about these 3D waves as wave packets?

Comment: The 3D waves can have any value of $\mathbf k$, and therefore any value of $\lambda$. Can you clarify why you think this is not the case?

Comment: @JohnRennie yeah, sorry, so.. from the formula above it seems to me that plane waves can not be continuous (i.e., defined from $−\infty$ to $+\infty$) - because $\vec{k}$ then (as I understand that) will have infinite length, which mean infinite small, or undefined $\lambda$. Whereas sine waves can have both various $\lambda$ (as Fourier series tells them) and being continuous, and this is confusing.

Comment: $|k| = 2\pi/\lambda$ so zero k corresponds to infinite $\lambda$ and vice versa. Neither k nor $\lambda$ can be zero or infinite but both have a continuous range in between.

Comment: @JohnRennie, somehow I thought (mistakenly) that the length of $k$ must be equal to a whole interval where wave is continuous (has the same $\lambda$, which in case of field modes is from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$). Still have no clue where these $2\pi$ should go or come from though (say, where to put it on a graph between wave peaks) to make correct definition)) but I guess that is bearable question for another time!

Comment: The $2\pi$ comes from the definition of the angular frequency $\omega = 2\pi f$. We define $k$ so that $\omega/k = v$ in the same way that $f\lambda = v$.